# Does Flurry provide new SDk for each app>

Tags: android, ios, flurry

This question might seem very poor, but still I want to know the answer. Because for the first time I am using Flurry.

Whenever I go to Flurry dashboard and try to download the SDK, it asks me to select and application. The app which I select has some category such as game-arcade, app-lifestyle etc.

As per my knowledge an SDK is universal for all types of applications/ games. It just differs with application Ids.

If I am correct why they ask me to select an application for downloading SDK> Does Flurry SDK different for each application?

If SDK is universal, Flurry must change its SDK download option. It is very annoying and confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, flurry does not provide a new SDK for each app, they are asking you to select an app so that they can provide you with the correct API key.

Since the page you are redirected to contains a piece of code which you can copy paste into your app they just make sure that the correct API key is there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got confused by its behaviour. But still they can change it. If user wants to know his APP_ID he can go to app dashboard and get it.

Comment: Yes it is a bit confusing. Just make sure that if you do copy the flurry SDK from one project to an other that it is the latest version of the SDK.